# table definition statement for cassandra for range queries?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cassandra-2.0

Here is the table data

```
video_id uuid
user_id timeuuid
added_year int
added_date timestamp
title text
description text
```

I want to construct table based on the following query

`select * from video_by_year where added_year<2013;`

create table videos_by_year (

```
video_id uuid
user_id timeuuid
added_year int
added_date timestamp
title text
description text
PRIMARY KEY ((added_year) added_year)
```

) ;

**NOTE**: I have used `added_year` as both primary key and clustering key which is not correct I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one of the issues with data modeling in cassandra is that the first component - the partition key - must use "=". The reason for this is pretty clear if you realize what cassandra's doing - it uses that value, hashes it (md5 or murmur3), and uses that to determine which servers in the cluster own that partition.

For that reason, you can't use an inequality - it would require scanning every row in the cluster.

If you need to get videos added before 2013, consider a system where you use some portion of the date as partition key, and then SELECT from each of those date 'buckets', which you can do asynchronously and in parallel. For example:

```
create table videos_by_year (
 video_id uuid
 user_id timeuuid
 added_date_bucket text
 added_date timestamp
 title text
 description text
 PRIMARY KEY ((added_date_bucket), added_date, video_id)
) ;
```

I used text for added_date_bucket so you could use 'YYYY', or 'YYYY-MM' or similar. Note that depending on how quickly you add videos to the system, you may even want 'YYYY-MM-DD' or 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH:ii:ss', because you'll hit a practical limit of a few million videos per bucket.

You could get clever and have the video_id be a timeuuid, then you get added_date and video_id in a single column.

Comment: what is practical limit of a few million videos per bucket you are talking about?

Comment: There's a hard cap of 2 billion cells per partition. With your scheme, you have 4 cells per row, which gives you a 500M row hard cap. Practically, though, very wide rows are less desirable - they don't perform as well, they slow compaction, and you end up touching a lot more stables pee read than very small partitions, which means it's slower.

Comment: if video_is is unique, how would it lead to wide row?

Comment: Good question, relates to the overloading of the term 'row' in cassandra. When I say "very wide rows", I mean "very wide partitions". In Cassandra, the on-disk row ('partition') is based on the first element of the primary key (added_date_bucket, in my example). Each CQL Row (video/user/timestamp/title/description) is physically stored on disk in order per added_date_bucket. That's where the 2B cell limit comes in.